# Reference the oncomplete event by an external java script function

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to do some logic at the oncomplete attribute of the a4j:commandButton  ,but my logic is too complicated ,  can I reference the code using a java script functions located in a external java-script file to have a better maintenance ? I found it has error because the JavaScript file cannot understand the EL expression .

For example , originally I have ,

```
<a4j:commandButton id="btn1" action="#{MBena1.action1}" oncomplete="if( {MBena1.variable1}){Richfaces.showModalPanel('modelPanel1');};if (......) then ">
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{MBena1.action1}" oncomplete="Btn1OnComplete();">
```

the code is put inside the java script function Btn1OnComplete() which is located in a external java-script file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the bean value as an argument:

```
oncomplete="Btn1OncOmplete(#{mBean1.value});"
```

and then, in the external javascript function you don't need to write any jsf-related code.